# Why my changes not visible in svn diff if I replace pattern in multiple files with find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g'?

Tags: linux, svn, sed

Why my changes not visible in svn diff if I replace pattern in multiple files with find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/abc/xyz/g' ?

Comment: I assume you did not modify any files that are part of your SVN repository.

Comment: they are part of svn repository